# How do I execute a file in Cygwin?

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

How can I execute `a.exe` using the Cygwin shell?

I created a C file in Eclipse on Windows and then used Cygwin to navigate to the directory. I called gcc on the C source file and `a.exe` was produced. I would like to run `a.exe`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

./a.exe at the prompt

Comment: `./a` also works; Cygwin is smart enough to figure to treat `a.exe` as `a` (for compatibility with Unix, which doesn't use a default `.exe` suffix for executables).

Answer (score 11):

you should just be able to call it by typing in the file name.  You may have to call ./a.exe as the current directory is usually not on the path for security reasons.

Answer (score 6):

just type ./a in the shell

Comment: Do you know why this works. ./a.exe makes sense but without extension this should not run. Any specific reason?

Comment: That would probably be cygwin figuring out things and being smart. UNIX-programs usually don't have a file extension, so if cygwin aims to give a  UNIX-feeling on Windows it makes sense to give the option to let out the program file extension.

Answer (score 3):

gcc under cygwin does not generate a Linux executable output file of type " ELF 32-bit LSB executable," but it generates a windows executable of type "PE32 executable for MS Windows" which has a dependency on cygwin1.dll, so it needs to be run under cygwin shell. If u need to run it under dos prompt independently, they cygwin1.dll needs to be in your Windows PATH.

-AD.

Comment: How can i eliminate this dependancy if i want to run my program in another computer without cygwin

Comment: You can try to use -mno-cygwin to remove it, but then you are missing all the UNIX APIs it provides; -mno-cygwin is usually used with MinGW (www.mingw.org).

Answer (score 2):

To execute a file in the current directory, the syntax to use is: `./foo`

As mentioned by allain, `./a.exe` is the correct way to execute a.exe in the working directory using Cygwin.

Note: You may wish to use the `-o` parameter to `cc` to specify your own output filename. An example of this would be: `cc helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

Thomas wrote:

> Apparently, gcc doesn't behave like the one described in The C Programming language

It does in general.  For your program to run on Windows it needs to end in .exe, "the C Programming language" was not written with Windows programmers in mind.  As you've seen, cygwin emulates many, but not all, features of a POSIX environment.

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently, gcc doesn't behave like the one described in The C Programming language, where it says that the command cc helloworld.c produces a file called a.out which can be run by typing a.out on the prompt.

A Unix hasn't behaved in that way by default (so you can just write the executable name without ./ at the front) in a long time. It's called a.exe, because else Windows won't execute it, as it gets file types from the extension.

Answer (score -2):

Just call it

```
> a
```

Make sure it will be found (path).

Comment: Putting the current directory `.` in your `$PATH` is a bad idea. If you want to execute a command in your current directory, type `./a`.

Answer (score -5):

When you start in Cygwin you are in the "/home/Administrator" zone, so put your a.exe file there.

Then at the prompt run:

> cd a.exe

It will be read in by Cygwin and you will be asked to install it.

Comment: `cd` changes to a specified directory. And if you've just created a `.exe` file by invoking the compiler you're not going to be asked to install anything. (And normally you *won't* be in `/home/Administrator`; you'll be in the home directory for your user name.)