# How do I execute a .lua file in CygWin?

Tags: windows, lua, cygwin

I have just installed CygWin and curl because I wanted to do something unrelated. But now, I want to execute a .lua file in CygWin and I want the results to print on the current window, the CygWin window. I want it to be like the equivalent of just opening CMD and then do `cd <directory where the file is>`. And then just do `<filename>.lua` and it prints the results. So how would I go about doing that? Sorry, I'm kinda new to Linux, Unix, CLI, ect., and I don't know much about the bash command.

I tried using the method from here: [How do I execute a file in Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999/how-do-i-execute-a-file-in-cygwin)
I just did `./<filename>.lua` and I get

```
./<filename>.lua: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `"Hello world"'
./<filename>.lua: line 1: `print("Hello world")'
```

The file just has

```
print("hello world")
```

Comment: have you installed the lua package ? `cygcheck -c lua` to do it from cygwin terminal

Comment: checkout file encoding.

Comment: I did `cygcheck -c` and lua was not listed there. If I do `cygcheck -c lua` it just says `Package Version Status`, but lua is not listed. I was not aware that I need to install lua for cygwin64? Oh, and sorry. I would have replied earlier but I was completely busy doing something throughout the day and I totally forgot about this.

@moteus What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is marked as an executable, running `./<filename>.lua` will default to executing the file as a *shell script*, (i.e., `sh`, `bash`, `zsh`, etc.). This results in the error you see, which is easily recreated.

In `bash`:

```
$ echo 'print("Hello world")' > script.sh && chmod +x script.sh && ./script.sh
./script.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `"Hello world"'
./script.sh: line 1: `print("Hello world")'
```

The first thing you need to do is make sure Lua is installed (rerun the Cygwin setup GUI, or use a tool like `apt-cyg`), and is located in your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#Unix_and_Unix-like).

Then instead of executing the file directly, run it with the Lua interpreter.

```
$ lua <filename>.lua
```

---

Alternatively, use a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) directive to instruct the shell on how the file should be executed.

Comment: Wow, I don't even know what you did with that `bash` thing. Again, I am not really that good with Linux, Unix, CLI, ect. Anyway, I did what you said. I did a search for apt-cyg, installed it. But I actually installed `lua5.1` with the Cygwin setup GUI. So I went ahead and did `lua-5.1 <filename>.lua` and it printed. Thank you guys for helping a noob like me.

Comment: @rumpled105 `echo` prints its arguments to the standard output; `>` redirects that output into the `script.sh` file, overwriting its contents. `&&` executes the next command if the last command succeeded (return status of `0`). `chmod +x` marks a file as executable. `./script.sh` runs that file. You'll pick these things up in time by playing around in your shell, and reading some documentation. Make sure to accept the answer if it helped, so others know that your problem has been solved. Cheers.

Comment: I suggest that using a `#!/usr/bin/lua` shebang line is the preferred way to do this.

Comment: @KeithThompson `#!/usr/bin/env lua`, generally, no? Having the Lua interpreter in your path is ideal, still, for normal use.

Comment: @Oka: Under Cygwin, the Lua interpreter will be `/usr/bin/lua` unless you install it manually. There's no universal guarantee that `env` is `/usr/bin/env`, though it is on Cygwin. I've discussed the pros and cons of the `#!/usr/bin/env` hack [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454).